# Asynchronous replacement for Celery

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery, gevent

We're  using Celery for background tasks in our Django project.
Unfortunately, we have many blocking sockets in tasks, that can be established for a long time. So Celery becomes fully loaded and does not respond.

Gevent can help me with sockets, but Celery has only experimental support of gevent (and as I found in practice, it doesn't work well).
So I considered to switch to another task queue system.

I can choose between two different ways:

1. Write my own task system. This is a least preferred choice, because it requires much time.
2. Find good and well-tried replacement for Celery that will work after monkey patching.

Is there any analogue of Celery, that will guarantee me execution of my tasks even after sudden exit?

Comment: I think the eventlet support in Celery is probably more tested, but many run Celery+gevent in production, so chances are the problems you're having originates from your own code.

Comment: @asksol can you give me docs for integrating gevent with monkey patching in Celery?

Comment: Like how? Using `-P gevent` the worker already is patched

Comment: @asksol i have tested it. We use django-celery and run worker through manage.py, so we need to gevent-patch before celery initialization. I fixed this and now everything works fine. You can write answer below (like your first comment) and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Zeromq might be suitable for your use case.

See- https://serverfault.com/questions/80679/how-to-pick-between-rabbitmq-and-zeromq-or-something-else

You will however need to write your own messaging library to persist messages.

Comment: This is the same as "write my own task system". ZeroMQ is a low-level library for sending messages between applications, not a distributed task queue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use Celery + eventlet? It works well in our project